# Terminal randomly disappears from Alt-Tab list, Unity launcher.

Tags: unity, 11.10, command-line

I like the terminal, it's handy to have open but this happens eveytime:

1. open terminal
2. type something in it
3. switch to another program
4. terminal is closed

:-/ This happens even if I just type something in the command line and leave it there, or if I open a program through the command line or if I'm just looking through my folders...

---

**edit**
Sorry this is the true chain of events:

1. List item
2. open terminal
3. switch to another program
4. alt-tab doesn't display it
5. click on terminal in the task bar
6. opens new terminal

Comment: Try running the terminal with the command `gnome-terminal > ~/log.txt 2>&1`. Then check if there is any output in log.txt

Comment: Nope nothing in the log file...

Comment: How quickly does it happen? - If you switch to another, non-maximised, window that doesn't obscure the terminal window, you should be able to see if there's a delay, if there are any messages, etc

Comment: Ok... sorry I'm a bit of an idiot and I had too many windows open - problem redefinition... They do not close, they hide behind all the other programs, alt-tabbing doesn't show it and if you scroll to the side bar and click it opens another one instead of bringing up the original (That's why I thought it closed sorry!)

Comment: I have seen this bug too.  I usually middle-click the titlebars of the apps in front of the terminal (or the top-panel for maximized windows) to send them to the background, until the terminal reappears.  It's rather frustrating.

Comment: It is! Especially since it doesn't seem to happen to any of my friends... they all looked at me as if I was mad! Was hoping it had happened to other people who were able to fix it!

Comment: Please, if you want it fixed, file a bug report.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).